# PySpark: Pivot / Flip table with column picked using a condition

Tags: python, join, pyspark, pivot

I am trying to solve a sort of pivoting problem that seems to be more complex than expected.

I have a table with this schema:

```
+-------+-------------+------------+------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
| Place | ReportMonth | MetricName | VolA | VolB | VolC | ValueA | ValueB | ValueC |
+-------+-------------+------------+------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
| ABC   | 2020-01-01  | M1         |   10 |   15 |   13 | 3.3    | 4.5    | 4.1    |
| ABC   | 2020-01-01  | M2         |    9 |   34 |   12 | 3.2    | 10.1   | 4.0    |
| ABC   | 2020-02-01  | M2         |    8 |    5 |   65 | 3.0    | 2.3    | 12.3   |
| DEF   | 2020-01-01  | M1         |   11 |   13 |   24 | 3.4    | 4.3    | 3.1    |
| DEF   | 2020-02-01  | M1         |    5 |   45 |    9 | 2.1    | 11.1   | 3.0    |
| DEF   | 2020-02-01  | M2         |    7 |    8 |   53 | 2.6    | 5.3    | 25.3   |
+-------+-------------+------------+------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

So, I have N metrics reported monthly per place (might be missing some months for some places).
For each metric there is a correspondent letter I need to report:

```
metrics_dct = {
    'M1': 'C',
    'M2': 'A'
}
```

I need to pivot this table (`sdf_mtr`) to have the following (`sdf_agg`):

```
+-------+-------------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
| Place | ReportMonth | M1VolC | M1ValueC | M2VolA | M2ValueA |
+-------+-------------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
| ABC   | 2020-01-01  | 13     | 4.1      | 9      | 3.2      |
| ABC   | 2020-02-01  | null   | null     | 8      | 3.0      |
| ABC   | 2020-01-01  | 9      | 3.0      | null   | null     |
| ABC   | 2020-02-01  | 53     | 25.3     | 7      | 2.6      |
+-------+-------------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
```

Essentially based on the name of the metric I have to pic the correct volume and value columns since A B and C are different type of measures that I have to include also in the new column name.
If it would have only be all columns the same per metric I could have used a normal pivoting. But I have a condition on the metric name to pic a desired column. I am currently using joins, but it is very inefficient:

```
grp_cols = ['Place', 'ReportDate']
sdf_agg = sdf_mtr.groupBy(grp_cols).count().drop('count')

for mtr_k, mtr_v in metrics_dct.items():  
  s_c_v = [
    F.col(f'Vol{mtr_v}').alias(f'{mtr_k}Vol{mtr_v}'), 
    F.col(f'Value{mtr_v}').alias(f'{mtr_k}Value{mtr_v}')
  ]
  sdf_agg = sdf_agg.join(
    sdf_mtr.filter(F.col('MetricName') == mtr_k).select(grp_cols + s_c_v),
    grp_cols,
    'left'
  )
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to do it avoiding joins? I managed with joins but it takes ages even with a small table. I was thinking of broadcast join but I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot the dataframe and aggregate values according to your requirements, currently I am taking max value if more than one value is available as

```
df.groupBy('Place','ReportMonth').\
   pivot('MetricName').\
   agg(f.max('VolA').alias('VolA'),f.max('ValueA').alias('ValueA'),f.max('VolB').alias('VolB'),f.max('ValueB').alias('ValueB')).\
   orderBy('Place','ReportMonth').show()

+-----+-----------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------+---------+
|Place|ReportMonth|M1_VolA|M1_ValueA|M1_VolB|M1_ValueB|M2_VolA|M2_ValueA|M2_VolB|M2_ValueB|
+-----+-----------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------+---------+
|  ABC| 2020-01-01|     10|      3.3|     15|      4.5|      9|      3.2|     34|     10.1|
|  ABC| 2020-02-01|   null|     null|   null|     null|      8|      3.0|      5|      2.3|
|  DEF| 2020-01-01|     11|      3.4|     13|      4.3|   null|     null|   null|     null|
|  DEF| 2020-02-01|      5|      2.1|     45|     11.1|      7|      2.6|      8|      5.3|
+-----+-----------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------+---------+
```

If you don't want to miss any value you can use `collect_list` instead of `max` and you are good to go.